# In Try - Catch how the line of error can be found

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, error-handling, try-catch, onerror

We are using visual studio. In case of try & catch we cant locate exactly the line of code for which error is thrown. Where as if we use resume, exact line is shown & we can make corrections there & test. Some times in testing environment reproducing error may not be possible in many cases. When error is thrown we have to atleast locate the error there itself. Further if procedure is a big one like having more than 400 lines then locating error without line of error is a big headache. When try catch is considered superior to on error statement, why is this feature not available? While we were using vb6 we could just type resume & check the error line. In vb.net we are searching for that feature.

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've already tried? 

Nonetheless, you can `Catch` (preferably) specific `Exceptions` and use their methods (ex: `.StrackTrace`) to return exception related data.

Comment: In the main file menu open "Debug" then "Exceptions..." in the dialog, find the entry named "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" and check the box in the "Thrown" column. Visual studio will now break at the point any CLR exception is thrown, rather then just at unhandled exceptions.

Comment: If procedure has 400 lines of code you're probably thinking in terms of "procedural code" - VB.net is *object-oriented*, VB6 wasn't. With OOP you should be writing lots of small objects that do one thing and do it well. 400 lines to do one thing seems unprobable. I've seen 1200-liner *procedures* in VB6 turn into 10-liner *methods* in .net; 10 lines are much easier to follow than 1200...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB6 the `Err` object is rather primitive, and gives you basic information about an error - a number and a message. "Error" state was easy to dismiss (`On Error Resume Next`) and proper error handling would obscure any method's intent.

.NET exceptions are more sophisticated. They're special objects that can actually contain every single bit of available information that's needed to locate an error - including the specific line of code that caused it.

That's because exceptions *bubble up* until they're caught (in a *catch*) block, and if they're not, they are *unhandled* and cause the program to stop. The exception will contain not only the type of error with a description and the very line of code that has *thrown* it, but also every single call that led to it - doing that in VB6 would require tremendous amount of meticulous "stack trace" building that could easily start lying, and wouldn't give you exact line numbers. .NET stack traces never lie.

To view the stack trace, you can place a breakpoint in any *catch* block and look at the exception's properties.

You can't *resume* like you would in VB6, because there could be dozens of method calls between the line that threw the exception and the line that catches it. But, like in VB6, you can move the yellow "current instruction" marker to another line and resume execution and re-run the *try* block line-by-line (F10) to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Go to the Debug menu.
2. Click on the the Exceptions... choice.
3. The following dialog should appear:
   [image]

Note the Common Language Runtime Exceptions checkbox is checked.

Upon clicking OK, now when you debug your code anytime an exception is thrown by your code or the .NET Framework, the debugger will halt on the line that threw the exception. This makes finding where something is "breaking" much easier.

Comment: What is the difference between thrown and user-handled? I am using visual studio 2008 express edition.

Comment: Thrown has the debugger stop on the line where the actual exception happened, whereas user-handled code be in the same method or elsewhere as exceptions bubble up until something handles the exception; if left unhandled by your code, then ultimately the .NET Framework will handle an exception and display an error page for you.

Comment: If i set it as "thrown" in debug->Exception menu then does it effects my project after building the project also?Or does it effect the exe i created? Also what if i set bothy thrown and user handled?

Comment: What if i make use of pdb files which gives line number in stacktrace.Does it contain my entire code which can be seen easily?

Comment: No, this is entirely a Visual Studio setting, it does not affect the built `.exe`. If you set both, then `Thrown` will trump `User Handled`, because `throw` happens before `catch`. Since this is happening inside of Visual Studio, you will automatically be put on the line number that the `throw` happened at and the debugger will be active so you can use the normal debugging capabilities (local variables, immedate window, mouse-over variables, etc.).